# Find() with Deep Associations using Containable, Model associations

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to build a view showing a table of a user's memos. Memos have a type (memo_type) and several authors -- authors table is made up of records:  `id, memo_id, user_id, precedence`, and MemoType is  `id, memo_type_desc`.  (Memos also have an owner (Memo.user_id), but that's a simple query and I have a separate table which works fine)

The idea is that when I view details about a user, I display a table of all the memos the user is listed as an author, and include the memo type (Letter, Presentation, etc.)

So although I can get the array I need from a read() with recursive=3 (*see More below*), this is slow and retrieves a TON of data, so I'm trying to use contain. (I could just leave out the memo_type_desc but the end-users want it.)

OK, so I put `public $actsAs = array('Containable');`
 in `app_model.php`

A big thing to note here is that I get the same array back regardless of the additional level of association for MemoTypes -- when I add  `=> array('MemoTypes.memo_type_desc')`  I don't see an additional level in the array. And with this third level of association I also get an error:

*Warning (512): Model "Memo" is not associated with model "MemoTypes" [CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 343*

The model associations are below, and here's the View function in user_controller. Any idea what's wrong with my Memo/MemoTypes association or find() syntax?

Edit:  Oh, and I'm a cake newbie and I inherited this application.
PS, the table is built by a foreach in view.ctp, but pagination would sure be better, but no idea where to start. =O

```
// Trying to get Containable method to work...
$this->set('userstuff', $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'Author.user_id',
        'Author.precedence',
        'Author.memo_id' => array(
            'Memo.memo_type_id' => array(
                'MemoTypes.memo_type_id' // <--problem here?
            )
        )
    )
)));
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1026
                    [group_id] => 2
                    [name] => John Doe
                    [username] => jd20001
                    [grpnum] => 99
                    [created] => 2010-03-22 15:08:35
                    [modified] => 2012-04-05 13:31:15
                )

            [Author] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 1026
                            [precedence] => 0
                            [memo_id] => 2579
                            [Memo] => Array
                                (
                                    [memo_type_id] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 1026
                            [precedence] => 0
                            [memo_id] => 2583
                            [Memo] => Array
                                (
                                    [memo_type_id] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array...
```

More:

```
// Works, but retrieves entire users/memos tables so large memory footprint
$this->User->recursive = 3;
$this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
```

User.php:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Group' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
    )
);
var $hasMany = array(
    'Author' => array(
        'className' => 'Author',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true
    ),
    'Memo' => array(
        'className' => 'Memo',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

Memo.php:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Author' => array(
        'className' => 'Author',
        'foreignKey' => 'memo_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'order' => 'precedence'
    )
);
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'MemoType' => array(
        'className' => 'MemoType',
        'foreignKey' => 'memo_type_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Memo_type.php:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Memo' => array(
        'className' => 'Memo',
        'foreignKey' => 'memo_type_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, lots more reading and I finally 'get it' (and just an hour of effort after posting my question... funny how that works).

User and Group give me my main info, then Memo lets me build a table of 'owned' documents, and Author gives me data on the all docs where user is listed as an author! Wow, after a year of working with CakePHP I'm only now really appreciating it :)

```
$this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'Group',
        'Memo',
        'Author' => array(
            'Memo' => array(
                'MemoType' => array(
                    'fields' => array('memo_type_desc')
                )
            )
        )
    )
)));
```